# Override Qt slot in subclass

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I have a base class, which defines a Qt slot

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        connect(otherobject, SIGNAL(mySignal), this, SLOT(mySlot));
    }
public slots:
    virtual void mySlot()
    {}
}
```

Subclass A just implements some other stuff. Subclass B overrides the slot

```
class SubB : Base
{
public:
    SubB() : Base() 
    {
        // Necessary?
        connect(otherobject, SIGNAL(mySignal), this, SLOT(mySlot));
    }
public slots:
    virtual void mySlot() override
    {}
}
```

Does the override of the slot also replace the connection, which was done before in the Bass constructor (I.e. The connect in SubB would be unnecessary)?

Comment: To be 100% correct, don't forget that Base should inherit from `QObject`  and you have to put the Q_OBJECT macro inside both classes ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to put the same `connect` in the subclass constructor. When a `SubB` object is created, the `connect` in the `Base` constructor will connect the right slot (the one overridden in SubB).

Comment: That's what I was hoping. Couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: @Simon It'd really help to look at the code generated by moc for the implementation of `Base`. You can easily see how the slot is called.

Answer (score 12):

It gets better: you don't need any special treatment for the slot in the derived class. There's no need to make it virtual (it already is per C++ semantics), and there's no need to make it a slot again (it already is per Qt semantics). It is incorrect to add the second connection in `Derived`, it'll simply result in the slot being activated twice per every activation of the signal.

Remember that signals and slots are regular C++ methods, and that slots are invoked from machine-generated code that looks exactly as if you called the slot without specifying the particular class it should be in. Thus a virtual slot acts as you think it should, given the semantics of C++.

The below is sufficient:

```
class Base : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Base(QObject * src, QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
  { connect(src, SIGNAL(mySignal), SLOT(mySlot)); }
  Q_SLOT virtual void mySlot() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Derived(QObject * src, QObject * parent = 0) : Base(src, parent) {}
  void mySlot() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE { ... }
};
```